# What is ExifInterface in android?

Tags: android

I come to know about ExifInterface from [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/) but I don't understand the exact usage of this Library.

Comment: Please read the "How do I ask good questions?" guidance http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: check this link to know what is Exif android has introduced new interface for this http://yuvarockers.blogspot.in/2017/05/exifinterface-in-android.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52135661/6401241

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html):

> [`ExifInterface`] is a class for reading and writing Exif tags in a JPEG file or a RAW image file.

[Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) is a specification for supporting metadata in a file, mostly used for JPEG, TIFF, and other image formats. The `TAG_`-prefixed constants on `ExifInterface` identify common tags, though not every image will have every tag. Tags that are popular among developers include `TAG_ORIENTATION` (indicating the orientation of the camera when the image was captured) and the `TAG_GPS_`-prefixed family (for geotagging).

Comment: So, you mean this is only helpful when we are working with images?

Comment: @sodhankit: Correct.

Comment: Ok thanks....a lot.