# exifinterface 27.1.0 , animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 , All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version

Tags: android, gradle

why gradle always say

> "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 27.1.0. Examples include
>   `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1` and
>   `com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0`"

where is 27.1.0 ??

build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'

implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same problem. it's because of some of libraries that I've used. I think it is `picasso`.

So now you can add exifinterface library

```
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1"
```

**UPDATE**

If you use androidx, use this

```
implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0"
```

That's work for me

According to this [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html) , it's for handle [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif?utm_campaign=android_launch_exifsupportlibrary_122116&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog) info of pictures

> the ability to read and write Exif tags embedded within image files: now with 140 different attributes (almost 100 of them new to Android 7.1/this Support Library!) including information about the camera itself, the camera settings, orientation, and GPS coordinates.

Some of EXIF info show in below picture

[image: EXIF]

Comment: @Radesh What does this library do exactly?

Comment: I have the same problem with picasso.
I fixed with:
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Got this error while trying to use picasso, ended up fixing by adding the following dependency:

`implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"`

This is used for handling EXIF data for pictures. Most photos will have EXIF data associated with them, such as the location of where the photo was taken, the time and date, etc..