# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification although using same version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, gradlew

Following are dependencies declaration in gradle file

```
ext {
supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'
firebaseVersion = '16.0.3'
playServicesVersion = '15.0.1'
 }
 dependencies {

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation project(':pageIndicator')
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'



implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

//play services
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${playServicesVersion}"
//play services

//firebase
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${firebaseVersion}"
//firebase

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
implementation 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:2.4.0'

implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.11'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'


}
```

Following are log for androidDependacies task run

```
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3@aar
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3@aar
+--- :pageIndicator (variant: debug)
+--- com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828@aar
+--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.30.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.evernote:android-job:1.1.11@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-audience:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.3@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3@aar
+--- com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1@aar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5@jar
+--- com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:2.4.0@aar
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9@jar
+--- com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1@aar
+--- com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3@aar
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2@jar
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.30.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1@aar
+--- net.vrallev.android:cat:1.0.5@aar
+--- com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1@jar
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.3@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5@jar
+--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0@jar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0@aar
+--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0@jar
+--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0@jar
+--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0@jar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0@aar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0@jar
+--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0@aar
+--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0@jar
+--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0@jar
+--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0@jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.2@aar
\--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0@aar
```

I don't understand why it is showing the message

Comment: `firebase-core` and `firebase-messaging` are not same

Comment: because it is not available for that version shows following error Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.3

Comment: its for picasso check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52135661/6401241

Answer (score 0):

I usually take care of this error by putting this in the gradle file:

```
// use default version for all support repositories
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion 'PUT_THE_VERSION_YOU_WANT' //27.1.1 in your case
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might have to add multiDexEnabled true inside android. What this basically does is force everything to use a specific version, so they won't have any conflicts.